# Octave How to set Default Marker Size?

Tags: plot, octave, markers

According to what I know, to set a default size for Octave plot markers I should use:

```
set(0, "defaultmarkermarkersize", 10)
```

But it does not work, returning:

```
error: invalid default property specification
```

What is the correct property specification?

Comment: set(0, "defaultlinemarkersize", 15);

Comment: That works, thanks. I've searched here and there but the documentation is kinda lacking on this.

Comment: Along the same line, how to set the default font as bold?

`set(0,"defaulttextfontweight", "bold");`

does not work, neither causes and error.

Comment: The documentation [actually covers this in reasonable detail](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Managing-Default-Properties.html), you just need to know where / how to look :). As a tip, I find the best way to search the octave documentation to be using the "site:" tag in Google or Duckduck go. e.g. `"set(0, " site:https://octave.org/doc/interpreter` gave the linked page as the top result.

Comment: I did check that page, and it is useful. What's missing is a complete list of the properties that can be set.

Comment: @FabioCapezzuoli just execute `set(0)` and you'll get a list (but not with the defaults)